# how to setattribute of a javascript object dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am looking to set an attribute of an object dynamically. Look at the example below.

```
function testFunc(type, scope){
    this.scope = scope;
    this.scope.setAttribute(type, true);
    this.doSome = function(){return //Something;}
}
```

but I realized that `setAttribute` method is only available for DOM elements. Is there a way i can set an attribute dynamically to a js object ?

Comment: Are you looking for `this.scope[type] = true`?

Comment: Yes absolutely, just figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function testFunc(type, scope){
    this.scope = scope;
    this.scope[type]= true;
    this.doSome = function(){return //Something;}
}
```

should do the trick.